Would using an DART-style impactor to divert an asteroid headed for Earth result in ejecta that would trigger Kessler Syndrome?
I'd be interested in any studies that have investigated the probability of Kessler Syndrome being triggered as a side effect of using a DART-style impactor to redirect an Earth-bound asteroid.
Also very cool - try doing a Google search using a Chrome browser for "DART Mission"!

Answer: No. Intervention would need to occur so far away from Earth that debris density would be low, and debris would follow hyperbolic (or impact)  trajectories
An impactor would be a poor choice for preventing a collision with a with a near-Earth asteroid. It is much more desirable to keep the object intact and alter its trajectory to avoid Earth, rather than turn it into shrapnel.

Scientists involved in NEO research have also considered options for
actively averting the threat if an object is found to be on a
collision course with Earth.[73] All viable methods aim to deflect
rather than destroy the threatening NEO, because the fragments would
still cause widespread destruction.[13] Deflection, which means a
change in the object's orbit months to years prior to the predicted
impact, also requires orders of magnitude less energy.[13]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-Earth_object

The earlier the intervention occurs, the smaller the delta-V needed for collision avoidance. So, even if an impactor was chosen rather than thrust deflection, early intervention would produce a diffuse debris cloud. Each piece of debris would make either a single pass of Earth in a hyperbolic trajectory, or Earth impact. Debris is unlikely to enter LEO orbit (LEO would greatly increase the risk of triggering Kessler syndrome).
According to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_impact_avoidance

It has been estimated that a velocity change of just .035 m/s ÷ t
(where t is the number of years until potential impact) is needed to
successfully deflect a body on a direct collision trajectory. Thus for
a large number of years before impact, much smaller velocity changes
are needed.

An ion thruster has exhaust velocity of around 20-50km/sec. DART impacted at 6.1km/sec. For a given mass of spacecraft, an ion thruster could impart much larger momentum on an asteroid by thrusting against  it ( or using  gravity traction) rather than colliding with it.

Does that also include the (low) possibility of the shrapnel impacting existing satellites & causing an event?

@fyrepenguin ... the probability of collision between asteroid debris and a satellite is proportional to the time the debris spends at highly populated LEO altitudes. An impact trajectory or hyperbolic trajectory has much lower collision risk than existing objects in LEO

Also: Kessler Syndrome would be the least of our worries when enough debris crosses LEO to have a chance of causing a kessler event...

@Woody Thanks for taking a crack at this. In your efforts, were you not able to turn up any studies that considered the possibility of Kessler Syndrome as a possible side-effect of a DART-style mission? If so, reporting a negative finding could be interesting. It might encourage someone to apply for a grant to study this - if, that is, it's never been done before. See: "NASA spacecraft collision may have created a meteor shower that will last for 100 years".

@phil1008 ... I didn't find any studies but I confess I didn't look very hard. I recently gave a talk to our local Astronomy society on space debris and Kessler syndrome. My literature search for that was exhausting (if not exhaustive) but I didn't turn up anything relevant. If a collision occurs between two LEO objects, the debris scatters into mostly LEO where it causes further mischief. If the impactor is on a hyperbolic trajectory, it has a lower chance of collision in the first place and debris is scattered much more broadly. Of course it is all probabilities.

@Woody That's helpful, thanks! I'm going to hold out for a bit on accepting an answer to see if anyone else has come across a published study on the probabilities. You got my upvote.
